# Como relaciono estos datos al darlos de alta? +Laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos

tengo estas dos tablas, que se relacionan de 1 a 1, son datos de login y datos personales de usuario, como veis users lleva una clave foranea con el id de data, pero cuando doy de alta usuarios como veis el id no lo declaro, es autonumerico, como podría asignar esa clave foranea? un saludo y gracias de antemano.
He intentado como ha comentado un compañero sacar el id del último registro de la tabla data para darle el id a el registro de user pero me lo inserta vacío

```
 $perfil=Data::create([

            'activo' => "1",
            'nombre' => $data['nombre'],
            'sexo' => $data['sexo'],
            'telefono' => $data['telefono'],
            'imagen' => "image.jpg",
            'localizacion' => $data['localizacion'],
        ]);
        $user= Data::all();
        $ultimo = $user->last();

        return User::create([
            'datos_id' => $ultimo->id,
            'perfil' => "1",
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['pass']),
            'username' => $data['username'],


        ]);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código como texto por favor (no como imagen).

Comment: No se entiende que entidad tiene la llave foránea  ?

Comment: Cierto, ya está el codigo añadido y la clave foránea se refiere a la de la segunda imagen, datos_id es la clave foranea en la tabla user (id de data)

Comment: Ese 'datos_id' está en el array `fillable` del modelo User?

Comment: ahí estaba el error, no tenía incluido el campo en el array fillable, muchísimas gracias @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: @javip97 entonces deberías publicar tu solución y marcarla como aceptada para que de ese modo la pregunta quede cerrada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Asignación masiva](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Para usar el método `create()`, antes de hacerlo, deberás especificar un atributo `fillable` en el modelo, ya que todos los modelos Eloquent protegen contra la asignación masiva de forma predeterminada.

Entonces agrega a ese array todos los atributos que asignas en tu método `User::create()`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Los atributos que pueden asignarse masivamente.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['perfil', 'email', 'password', 'username', 'datos_id'];
}
```

No relacionado, pero esta lógica parece estar errada:

```
$user = Data::all();
$ultimo = $user->last();

return User::create([
    'datos_id' => $ultimo->id,
    // ...
]);
```

No tiene sentido consultar todos los registros que tienes de la tabla del modelo `Data` para obtener el último, y asignar su `id` al atributo `'datos_id'` del nuevo usuario que estás creando.

En cambio, tendría más sentido que asignes al atributo `'datos_id'`, la `id` del modelo `Data` que acabas de crear, que serán los datos que quieres relacionar a ese usuario (y además será el último, pues lo acabas de crear):

```
$perfil = Data::create([
    'activo' => "1",
    'nombre' => $data['nombre'],
    'sexo' => $data['sexo'],
    'telefono' => $data['telefono'],
    'imagen' => "image.jpg",
    'localizacion' => $data['localizacion'],
]);

return User::create([
    'datos_id' => $perfil->id, // <- Aquí!!
    'perfil' => "1",
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => Hash::make($data['pass']),
    'username' => $data['username'],
]);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de nuevo @porloscerros , es tal cual lo que hice a raiz de tu anterior respuesta, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes primero emplear la ejecución del perfil y te traerá el id

```
$perfil = Data::create([
    'activo' => 1,
    ...
]);

return User::create([
    'perfil' => $perfil->id, // Aqui obtienes el id del perfil
     ...
]);
```

Comment: la idea no es mala, no sé si expliqué bien que el id es autonumerico en la tabla, aún así he intentado sacarlo a través de una consulta e insertarlo y se me inserta vacío